# Deploying RabbitMQ using Desired State Configuration

Tags: powershell, rabbitmq

I have a requirement to deploy RabbitMQ to a bunch of servers and I was thinking to use PowerShell desired state configurations to automate the deployment.

Any thoughts ? directions ?

Comment: You've provided a direction (use DSC to deploy RabbitMQ).  It seems like a reasonable thing to do.  You haven't given us any programming-related questions to answer, though.

Comment: https://www.chef.io/chef/ why not ?